# Cancellation of visit visa at the airport

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, denial-of-entry, nigerian-citizens, visa-cancellation

My visit visa to the UK was cancelled on two reasons: not having enough cash at hand and disclosing to visit family and friends whereas it's not stated in the application form.

I made an appeal on return from the UK because I couldn't stay in the UK. I would lose my job in Nigeria. The appeal was rejected because it ought to have been done in the UK.

I want to know if I have been banned. It was not stated in the letter.

Comment: At which airport was the visa cancelled? What type of visa did you have?

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/59647/cancelled-uk-visa-at-airport-but-still-allowed-in-for-3-weeks-why-did-it-happen/59648#59648

Comment: @WeatherVane let's not be too hasty in accusing anyone of lying.  There are many innocent possibilities that could explain this.

Comment: @phoog I did not. I asked if OP thinks they *should have* lied, no suggestion that they did.

Comment: If your letter refers to refusal under Section V3.6 or 3.7 it's possible that you have a ban. If not, it's likely that you don't. For a better answer post the letter you have here, with the personal information blanked out.

Comment: "I made an appeal on return from the UK" makes sense, but "because I can't stay there and lose my job in Nigeria" doesn't.

Comment: @Akinwale Bamidele Does the letter refer to V9.2 and/or V9.3 Appendix V? It sounds as if your leave to enter may have been cancelled because of change of circumstances or purpose https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/674000/GGFR-Section-3-v29.0EXT.PDF#page59

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica Does 'I couldn't stay in the UK and appeal there because I would lose my job in Nigeria' make sense? That's what I assumed was the issue.

Comment: @mkennedy Thank you! That does make sense. Now, can you understand what's meant about the relatives? Was their existence disclosed in the visa application? If not, I can see a refusal at the border when the OP brought them up. If they were mentioned, was the applicant's plan to visit them mentioned in the application? Perhaps the OP was refused when it appeared to UK Immigration that the OP was changing his plan.

Comment: @DavidSupportsMonica From the OP’s question, I infer that he did not disclose having relatives/friends in the UK, and probably stated he was covering his own costs (hence the ‘lack of cash’ problem). What makes no sense to me is that a visitor whose visa is cancelled at the border cannot request an administrative review from within the UK since they won’t have been admitted https://www.gov.uk/ask-for-a-visa-administrative-review/if-your-visa-was-cancelled-at-the-border. I doubt TSE can answer unless the OP posts the visa cancellation letter, we’d just be conjecturing

Comment: @Traveller there are plenty of scammers out there who will happily conduct an “appeal” on behalf of someone for some money... might be the case here.

Comment: Agree with Traveller and Arthur's Pass: without seeing the visa cancellation letter, we're just guessing.